# Regular Expression To Match a Text Inside : -

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

I'm building a project that needs to match a text that is inside `:  text to match  -`. For example, if I have this string:

> nathanpc/ltweet: Asking a question at #StackOverflow: "Regular Expression To Match a Text Inside : -" - @devs

I want to match `Asking a question at #StackOverflow: "Regular Expression To Match a Text Inside : -"`. Everything that is after the first `:` and the last `-`, but what is the correct regular expression to do this?

*PS: I'm using Javascript with jQuery*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Perl-compatible regular expressions, like those found in most languages:

```
/:(.*)-/
```

You might not need the slashes, depending on the language. The capture group 1 will get the content you want.

The `.*` is a greedy matcher, so it will attempt to match as many characters as possible, up to the last dash in the input.

Comment: True +1. Simpler and immediate. Perhaps OP wants not group the spaces `/:\s(.*)\s-/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a greedy operator like `.` it will try to form the largest match possible (at least in Perl compatible regular expression engines)

So to match this something as simple as `:(.*)-` will work.

See this example script in Perl:

```
my $str = "Discard:Testing:- one two three -discard";
$str =~ m/:(.*)-/;
print $1;
```

`$1 = "Testing:- one two three"`

Or in javascript here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: Again, that won't work. How does Perl know not to stop at the first "-"?

Comment: It's a greedy operator. Perl tries to expand it maximally before it gives up.

Comment: The question is the definition of "giving up" :) Again, that won't work in general.

Comment: It's not the dot (`.`) that is greedy, but the asterisk (`*`). The corresponding non-greedy modifier is (`*?`), which can equally apply to a dot or any other regexp atom.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (ruby):

```
[^:]+:\s+([^-]+.*?)\s-
```

Test:

```
 test = "nathanpc/ltweet: Asking a question at #StackOverflow: 'Regular Expression To Match a Text Inside : -' - @devs"

 m = test.match /[^:]+:\s+([^-]+.*?)\s-/
```

then

```
 m[1].to_s
```

produces

```
Asking a question at #StackOverflow: 'Regular Expression To Match a Text Inside : -'
```

---

As others have noticed the much simpler `:(.*)-` works the same. Perhaps without spaces `:\s(.*)\s-`

Answer (score 0):

"Standard" regular expressions cannot parse this text exactly as you described. That parsing requires some *context*, that cannot be expressed with regexes. For example, when receiving the first "-", how does the expression not to end?

Out of my head, I can only come with Perl extended regular expressions, that allow sub-expression parsing, but it won't be easy, as you have to count the occurrences of ":" and "-" to match exactly the last one.